# How to refresh lotus notes with vba code?

Tags: vba, excel, lotus-notes

I have a vba code which downloads the attachments from lotus notes and mark the emails as read. But the problem is that the UI is not able to refresh itself. And it shows unread in UI even if the file has been downloaded. How can i correct this?

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim TimeToRun
Public RunWhen As Double
Const cRunInvtSecs = 5
Const cRunWhat = "Sheet1.Save_Attachments_Remove_Emails"
Sub StartTimer()
RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunInvtSecs)
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=True
'Call Save_Attachments_Remove_Emails

End Sub
Sub Save_Attachments_Remove_Emails()
'MsgBox ("Hello 2")
Const stPath As String = "C:\ZipLogs\"
Const EMBED_ATTACHMENT As Long = 1454
Const RICHTEXT As Long = 1

Dim noSession As Object
Dim noDatabase As Object
Dim noView As Object
Dim noDocument As Object
 Dim noRemoveDocument As Object
 Dim noNextDocument As Object

'Embedded objects are of the datatype Variant.
Dim vaItem As Variant
Dim vaAttachment As Variant

'Instantiate the Notes session.
Set noSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")

'Instantiate the actual Notes database.
'(Here is the personal e-mail database used and since it's a
'local database no reference is made to any server.)
'I have deleted the server name and database,(for security reasons), But the database is not on local system,it is on server.
 Set noDatabase = noSession.GETDATABASE("","")
' Please use this Open Function if the server is not referenced and GETDATABASE
' opens the db file if the file is in local system.
'Call noDatabase.Open("", "C:\notes\test.nsf")

'Folders are views in Lotus Notes and in this example the Inbox
'is used.
Set noView = noDatabase.GetView("($Inbox)")

'Get the first document in the defined view.
Set noDocument = noView.GetFirstDocument


'Iterate through all the e-mails in the view Inbox.
Do Until noDocument Is Nothing
Set noNextDocument = noView.GetNextDocument(noDocument)
Dim flag As Boolean
    flag = noDocument.GetRead
    'Call noDocument.MarkRead
If flag = False Then
'Check if the document has an attachment or not.
If noDocument.HasEmbedded Then
  Set vaItem = noDocument.GetFirstItem("Body")
  If vaItem.Type = RICHTEXT Then
    For Each vaAttachment In vaItem.EmbeddedObjects
     If vaAttachment.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT Then

        'Save the attached file into the new folder.
        vaAttachment.ExtractFile stPath & vaAttachment.Name
        'Set the e-mail object which will be deleted.
      '  Set noRemoveDocument = noDocument


      Call noDocument.MarkRead
      Call noView.Refresh

      End If

    Next vaAttachment
  End If
End If
End If


Set noDocument = noNextDocument
'Delete the e-mails which have an attached file.
' If Not noRemoveDocument Is Nothing Then
 ' noRemoveDocument.Remove (True)
 ' Set noRemoveDocument = Nothing
'End If
Loop

'Release objects from memory.
Set noRemoveDocument = Nothing
Set noNextDocument = Nothing
Set noDocument = Nothing
Set noView = Nothing
Set noDatabase = Nothing
Set noSession = Nothing

Call StartTimer
End Sub


Sub auto_close()
Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "Save_Attachments_Remove_Emails", , False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your database  track unread marks?

I think your code working in background lotus.

Mayby you should try to work on Lotus uiview? And write code on Lotus Designer?

from help:

create button on view and.. (modify code below for find interests documents)

This form action saves the current document, refreshes the view (called "Main"), and closes the document.

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
 ' Declare all variables
 Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
 Dim session As New NotesSession
 Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
 Dim view As NotesView
 Dim db As NotesDatabase
 'Set all variables
 Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
 Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
 Set view = db.GetView( "Main" )
 'Save current document, refresh "Main" view
 'and close document
 Call uidoc.Save
 Call view.Refresh
 Call workspace.ViewRefresh
 Call uidoc.Close
End Sub
```

or mayby You haven't got lotus designer and you must do it in excel?

all best.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a lotusscript version of your code and see the result. The API is used more in LS than COM and more reliant in the former.
Try the user name argument in the method.
Call  notesDocument .MarkRead(  [username]  ) 
If it works in LS, You can run it in notes or if needed call it as an agent.